# Included file's root path

Tags: php, file, path, include, root

how can i get "included file's root path" ?

```
d:\projects\project1\incs\inc.php :
```

In this file below line gives me `"d:\projects\project1\incs"`

```
<?php echo __DIR_; ?>
```

I want to get `"/projects/project1"`

I use that

```
str_replace("\\","/", str_replace(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)))), '', __DIR__))
```

but it's so complicated...

i want to use:

```
<img src="<?php echo ROOT_DIR ?>/images/image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the web-root, you can use:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

**Edit:** I just noticed your edit, and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is the root of your site relative to the file-system. It is not a value you want to use in html.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php), but if you want to be able to display images on your page, you'll need to use a URL rather than a file path. In that case, you'll want to use `"http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];?>/images/image.jpg" />
```